# Из строки записать значения в словарь, добавив свои значения

Tags: python, словари

Подскажите пожалуйста как преобразовать в Python строку вида `А:0.1,B:0.2,С,D,E:0.4` в словарь при этом добавив к С,D значение 1. После того как преобразовали в `"А":0.1, "B":0.2, "C":1, "D":1, "E":0.4`.
Оптимально ли будет через json?

```
import json
dict = json.loads('{"А":0.1,"B":0.2,"C":1,"D":1,"E":0.4}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'А:0.1,B:0.2,С,D,E:0.4'
d =  {k: float(v[0] if v else 1) for k, *v in (i.split(':') for i in s.split(','))}
```

Comment: Thank you, It's works!

Comment: @yakorovka если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Если проще то:

```
s = 'А:0.1, B:0.2, С, D, E:0.4'
s = s.split(', ')
d = {}

for i in s:
    if len(i) == 1:
        d[i] = 1
    else:
        d[i[0]] = i[2:]
print(d)
```